# Proof verification of $f(x) = \alpha x - E(\alpha x) < 1, \;\forall x\in\mathbb Z, \;\alpha \in \{\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q \}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

I'm wondering whether the below is a valid proof for:

> $f(x) = \alpha x - E(\alpha x) < 1, \;\forall x\in\mathbb Z, \;\alpha \in \{\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q \}$ where $E(x)$ is integer part of $x$

I've used two steps.

**Step 1**

Put $\mathbb I = \{\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q\}$ which denotes irrational numbers.

Let $\alpha = k + r, \; k \in \mathbb Z,\; r\in(0; 1),\; r\in \mathbb I$. Then the function may be rewritten as:

$$ 
\begin{align} f(x) & = \alpha x - E(\alpha x) \\ 
& = (k+r)x - E((k+r)x) \\
&= kx + rx - E(kx + rx) \\
&= rx - E(rx) \tag 1
\end{align} $$

Since $x$ may be arbitrary we need step 2.

**Step 2**

Let $rx = a + b, \; a\in \mathbb Z, \; b \in \mathbb I, b \in [0, 1)$. Rewrite $(1)$:

$$
$$ 
\begin{align} rx - E(rx) & = a + b - E(a + b) \\ 
& = a + b - a - E(b) \\
&= b - E(b) \\
&= b - 0 \\
&= b \tag 2
\end{align} $$
$$

But $b \in [0, 1)$ and therefore $f(x) \in [0, 1)$ which proves $f(x) < 1$

Comment: The ideas are generally fine, but there is one factual inaccuracy (and the proof can be shortened significantly by focusing only on Case 2).  It is not always true that $\alpha x$ can be written as $a+b$ where $a\in \mathbb Z$ and $b \in (0,1)$: the exception is when $x=0$.  But you don't need $b>0$, so you can relax this assertion (and then greatly simplify the proof).

Comment: Your proof is fine, but if $y\in \mathbb{R}$ is any real number, then $0\leq y-E(y)<1$. Why? Well, you've proved this kinda multiple times: If $y=n+r$ with $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $r\in \mathbb{I}\cap [0,1)$, then $y-E(y)=r$.

Comment: @ErickWong Thank you, that's a good point, I've included $0$ in the interval for $b$ which makes $a\in \mathbb Z,\; b \in [0, 1)$ a valid statement for $x = 0$

Comment: @roman Notice now that Step 2 works equally well for $\alpha x$ as it does for $rx$, making Step 1 redundant.